# Filter an array based on array of enum types

Tags: arrays, swift, enums

Say I have an array of Cats that I need to filter. Each Cat has a `furColor` array, something like `[.gray, .black, .tabby]`. So a Cat can be gray, or any combination of the three colors.

Given a separate array like `[.gray, .tabby]`, how can I filter all the cats down to just those that fit AT LEAST ONE of the colors in the input array?

```
class Cat {
    ...
    var furColor: [FurColor] = [.gray]

}

enum FurColor: String, CaseIterable {
    case gray = "gray"
    case black = "black"
    case tabby = "tabby"
}

let colorsToMatch = [.gray, .tabby] //match 1 or more of these
let filteredCats = cats.filter(???)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this out:

```
class Cat {
            
    var furColor: [FurColor] = [.gray]

}

enum FurColor: String, CaseIterable {
    case gray = "gray"
    case black = "black"
    case tabby = "tabby"
}

let colorsToMatch: [FurColor] = [.gray, .tabby] //match 1 or more of these
let filteredCats = cats.filter({!Set($0.furColor).intersection(Set(colorsToMatch)).isEmpty})
```